# symfony use free objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to build several objects in symfony, which will do specific work. For example one object `Parser` will have a public method `parse($text)` and will return parsed text. All other methods are `private` to manage the parsing.

Within this parsing methods, I want to exclude some work to other objects. For example `Clean` and `Highlight`.

I want to include `Parser` as service. But do I also need to create services of the other Objects to include them? I do not plan to use them in controllers. Within the `Parser` object I can call them just with

```
new Highlight();
```

But now I get a problem, because I want to use the Doctrine entity manager within `Highlight`. Within a service I would inject it via the service arguments, but because `Highlight` is no service that is not possible.

How should I inject Doctrine into this "free" Object `Highlight`. And generally, is it ok to use objects in like this in symfony?

Comment: yes - you can make anything you like a service in Symfony. http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a service for each object called from Parser unless you will independently need these sub-objects (Clean, Highlight). If you need to pass other things to your sub-objects, just pass them from the calling object (Parser). Just inject the entity manager into Parser, then pass that on to the sub-objects.

From Parser:

```
new Highlight($em);
```

Alternatively, you could use a variation of this by defining an abstract service where common dependencies are defined in the parent (abstract) service and then extend that service in dependent objects. See docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html) for details.